# Sort Output of foreach by value

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, foreach

I am trying to sort data outputted from a WordPress function, but I can't seem to get it to work. The function below gets a list of unique zip codes, along with a sum of point values for each zip code, all stored in the user meta table. I am trying to sort the list by the highest sum of point values. Any help is much appreciated.

```
function total_actions_map_leaderboard() {

    $user_args = array(             
        'number' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'User Zip Code',
        //'orderby' => array( 
            //'meta_value' => 'DESC',
        //),
    ); 

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query($user_args);
    $zipCode = array();
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
        $user_id = $user->id;
        $zipCode[] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'User Zip Code', true );
    }
    
    $unique_zc = array_unique($zipCode);

    foreach ( $unique_zc as $result ) {
        $zc_args = array( 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'User Zip Code',
                'value' => $result
            )
        ),
    );
    $zc_query = new WP_User_Query($zc_args);
    $sum = 0;

    foreach( $zc_query->get_results() as $zc ) {
            $user_id = $zc->id;
            $balance = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'mycred_default_total', true );
                $sum+= $balance;
     }

        echo '<div>'.$result.' '.$sum.'</div>';

    }  
}
add_shortcode('map-leaderboard','total_actions_map_leaderboard');
```

Comment: Store data from the foreach() into an array and sort by desired value. Then output it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Move the `echo` outside to a new `foreach()` after sort.

```
function total_actions_map_leaderboard() {

    $user_args = array(             
        'number' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'User Zip Code',
        //'orderby' => array( 
            //'meta_value' => 'DESC',
        //),
    ); 

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query($user_args);
    $zipCode = array();
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
        $user_id = $user->id;
        $zipCode[] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'User Zip Code', true );
    }
    
    $unique_zc = array_unique($zipCode);
    $sorted_zc = array();

    foreach ( $unique_zc as $result ) {
        $zc_args = array( 
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'User Zip Code',
                    'value' => $result
                )
            ),
        );

        $zc_query = new WP_User_Query($zc_args);
        $sum = 0;

        foreach( $zc_query->get_results() as $zc ) {
             $user_id = $zc->id;
             $balance = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'mycred_default_total', true );
             $sum += $balance;
         }
         
         // Unique zipcode used as key to store point sum
         $sorted_zc[$result] = $sum;
    }

    // Output zipcode & point by descending point order
    foreach(arsort($sorted_zc) as $zc => $point) {
         echo '<div>'.$zc.' '.$point.'</div>';
    }
    
}
add_shortcode('map-leaderboard','total_actions_map_leaderboard');
```